# how to get view's values in controller?

Tags: cakephp

In my controller i want to get the value as $this->data['controlname'].
But am using Event.observe for button submit. How do I get the element value in the controller? I am getting null value.

in my event.observer i gave "parameters:Form.serialize(Event.element(event).form)," but the value was null in controller.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Just check $`this->params` in Controller - all things relevant to the request (GET vars, named arguments, POST data, etc.) are stored there.